# Docker machine's database persists after docker-machine rm | How do I remove the db?

Tags: django, postgresql, ubuntu, docker-compose, docker-machine

Whenever I break the database on my local development instance I am able to easily run 'docker-machine rm dev-instance'. This works, and I can just recreate a new docker-machine with 'docker-machine create --driver virtualbox dev'. Then just rebuild the machine with 'docker-machine -f local.yml build' and 'docker-compose -f local.yml up'. All works great with this approach on Mac OS.

However, on my Ubuntu machine, when I run 'docker-machine rm -f dev-instance' it deletes the dev instance and I think all is fine. I go through the usual process of recreating my dev instance. It builds successfully, but way too fast -- it's not creating a new machine it doesn't look like.. It seems to be caching the last docker machine. I confirm this when I run 'docker-compose -f local.yml up'. This isn't very helpful though, because I still run into the same errors I had with my DB before -- I was hoping to nuke my instance of everything and start fresh, but I can't quite get it to work on Ubuntu.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, please let me know what other details would be useful to provide. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this was something I had trouble figuring out for quite a long time. Sorry to post and then answer myself right away, I guess stepping away from it for a few months was needed haha.

Anyways, I found this github issue related to my problem: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2419.

After reading that, I ran the following commands and seem to be fine now.

'docker-compose -f local.yml rm'
'docker-compose -f local.yml down -v'
'docker-machine rm -f -v dev'
'docker-machine create --driver virtualbox dev'
'eval $(docker-machine env dev)'
'docker-compose -f local.yml build && docker-compose -f local.yml up'

I think that it was the 'docker-compose -f local.yml rm' and the 'docker-compose -f local.yml down -v' that really did it for me. Hadn't ever tried that or heard of them as options before reading that thread I mentioned.

Hopefully this helps someone else out in the same boat :)